# Cannot install dotnet-sdk due to unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 18.10, dotnet

I followed the instructions given [Here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu16-04/sdk-current) to install dotnet-sdk-2.2. On running the last command, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.2 : Depends: aspnetcore-runtime-2.2 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.2 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Those instructions are clearly for 16.04 and 18.04. Looks like Microsoft does not support installation on 18.10. Pro Tip: Do NOT mix sources or packages intended for different releases of Ubuntu. Doing so may break your system quite horribly...which is why apt raised the error message instead.

Comment: I'll wait for the support then :-)